# in groupJoin method,the param 'TrightEnd' is type UnicastProcessor but size = 0

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
public static void testGroupJoin(){
    Flux<Integer> f1 = Flux.just(1,2,3,10,11,12,13,14);
    Flux<Integer> f2 = Flux.just(10,12,13,14,15,16);
    f1.groupJoin(f2,x->Flux.never(),y-> Flux.never(),(x,y)->{
        return x+","+y;
    }).subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

the y.size = 0  i dont know why;

i try use method  join() , is running well;

```
public static void testJoin(){
    Flux<Integer> f1 = Flux.just(1,2,3,10,11,12,13,14);
    Flux<Integer> f2 = Flux.just(10,12,13,14,15,16);
    f1.join(f2,x->Flux.never(),y-> Flux.never(),(x,y)->{
        return x+","+y;
    }).subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

i want get data {1:(10,12,13,14,15,16)},{2:(10,12,13,14,15,16)}....
and i know achieve the effect by use method join() and groupBy()
i just want know groupJoin how to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two is that `y` in `Flux.groupJoin` is a *Flux* of all elements from `f2` with overlapping windows (in this case all 6 elements). Thus the `resultSelector` will receive the following elements:

```
(1, Flux.just(10,12,13,14,15,16))
(2, Flux.just(10,12,13,14,15,16))
(3, Flux.just(10,12,13,14,15,16))
(10, Flux.just(10,12,13,14,15,16))
(11, Flux.just(10,12,13,14,15,16))
(12, Flux.just(10,12,13,14,15,16))
(13, Flux.just(10,12,13,14,15,16))
(14, Flux.just(10,12,13,14,15,16))
```

Meanwhile, `Flux.join` will emit an element for every window between f1 and f2 that overlaps, for a total of 8 × 6 = 48 elements. These are then send to the `resultSelector`:

```
(1, 10)
(1, 11)
...
(14, 15)
(14, 16)
```

To get the desired result using groupJoin, you have to process the Flux received by the resultSelector, for example:

```java
@Test
public void testGroupJoin() {
    Flux<Integer> f1 = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14);
    Flux<Integer> f2 = Flux.just(10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16);
    f1.groupJoin(f2, x -> Flux.never(), y -> Flux.never(),
                    (x, yFlux) -> yFlux.map(y -> x + "," + y))
            .concatMap(flux -> flux)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```